# How do I calculate count times for every char array with struct?

Tags: c

```
struct Page{
 char data[50];
 int count = 0; // ?
};
Page page[50];
```

I don't know how to save count for every char array.

for exmaple:

```
input: a c b
page[i].data[0] = a; // a_count = 1
page[i].data[1] = c; // c_count = 1
page[i].data[2] = b; // b_count = 1
```

my ideas is

```
paga[i].data[0].count++;
```

but, I don't know how to implement with struct.

Comment: How is this related to java?

Comment: @user7 sorry, I changed tag.

Comment: You will need a counter for each character.

Comment: @f1sh yes, but how can I do ?

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the input characters? I mean can they be any character or just alphabets?

Comment: What is the structure supposed to represent?  Is it given to you, or is it your own invention?

Comment: Adding onto @SaiSreenivas, do the characters include both uppercase and lowercase letters? Just one of the two?

Comment: @JohnBollinger  I created it myself.

Comment: Inasmuch as you didn't answer the first part of my question, I'm inclined to think that you don't have a clear idea of what the structure is supposed to represent. You seem, then, to have asked an X-Y question, and the structure as written is probably not appropriate to the task.  Take a step back, and explain more clearly what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @SaiSreenivas just alphabets

Comment: @parthlr just lowercase letters

Comment: If they are just alphabets then create an array (Freqs) of length 26 in the struct so that 0 maps to a and so on. With this, if you increase value at index 0 in Freqs it means no of  "a" has increased by one.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Oops. data is save alphabets, and counter is count times for each char.

Comment: ... and is it required to use a structure to solve the problem?  In any case, please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62623754/edit) to clarify your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a single integer `count`, you need an array to solve this issue. So you can define `Page` in the following way:

```
typedef struct Page
{
    char data[50];
    int countChar[TOTAL_CHARS];
} Page;
```

Now, we can't simply initialize an array inside a struct like we can in a function. So we have to manually initialize `countChar[]` with `0`. However, there is a trick that can save you from this tiresome process. And the trick is to use a macro like this:

```
#define NEW_PAGE { "", {0} }
```

and use it in the following way:

```
Page page[50] = NEW_PAGE;
```

Now, all you have to do is map the character to the index of `countChar[]` and increment its value by 1. This can be done in the following way:

```
page[0].countChar[ch - 'a']++;
```

Here, `ch` is the character from input. Considering all the input will be lowercase letters, subtracting `ch` with `'a'` will produce the required index that represent frequency of character `ch`. If the possible value of `ch` were all ASCII characters, we would simply replace `'a'` with `'\0'` and change size of `countChar[]` accordingly.

Here's a code that tests this idea:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define NEW_PAGE { "", {0} }
#define TOTAL_CHARS 26

typedef struct Page
{
    char data[50];
    int countChar[TOTAL_CHARS];
} Page;

int main()
{
    Page page[50] = NEW_PAGE;
    char input[] = "hello world";
    char ch;
    int i = 0;
    int frequency;

    while(input[i] != '\0')
    {
        ch = input[i];
        page[0].data[i] = ch;
        page[0].countChar[ch - 'a']++;
        i++;
    }

    for(i=0; i<TOTAL_CHARS; i++)
    {
        frequency = page[0].countChar[i];
        if(frequency != 0)
            printf("%c is present %d times\n", ('a'+i), frequency);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a single `int`, you could have an array of integers of length 26. This would hold the count of each lowercase letter in the array.

The integer values for lowercase letters range from **97 - 122**. To correspond each letter to an index in a 26 length array, you need to subtract 97 from the integer value of each `char` so that each char can correspond to an index from 0 - 25.

So your struct should look something like this:

```
struct Page{
 char data[50];
 int count[26];
};
```

If you had a `char` called `letter`, the way you would find the correct index of the `count` array and increment it would be:

```
int index = (int)letter - 97;
count[index]++;
```